# Confusing about Future Object in Dart -

Tags: dart, dart-html

Any idea what is wrong here?

I have a function which receive data from server by a rest call, which return Future object.

```
Future _function(){
 var future = _getWithID('path');
  future.then((data) {
    List<SOMEOBJECT> SOMEOBJECT = data["entities"].map((v) {
          return new SOMEOBJECT(
              id: v["properties"]["id"],
              name: titleize(v["properties"]["name"])
          );
        }).toList();
    return new Future.value(SOMEOBJECT.process(SOMEOBJECT));
  });
}
```

Model class for SOMEOBJECT

```
class SOMEOBJECT extends Model {

  int id;

  String name;

  SOMEOBJECT({this.id, this.name});

  static Map process(List<String> SOMEOBJECTS) {
    // map = {name: A, value:[{name:list<String>},{name:list<String>}]}
    return map;
  }
}
```

Cache object which try to cache in browser

```
class CacheManager {
  Map callbacks;
  Map cache;

  CacheManager(this.cache){
    callbacks = {};
  }

  Future setData(String key, Function updateFunction) {
    return chrome.storage.local.get(key).then( (resp){
      cache[key] = resp[key];

      return updateFunction().then((data) {
        chrome.storage.local.set({key: data});
        cache[key] = data;
      }).whenComplete( () {
        handleCallbacks(key);
      });
    });
  }

  void registerCallback(String key, Function callback) {
    callbacks[key] = callback;
  }

  void handleCallbacks(String key){
    if (callbacks[key] != null){
        callbacks[key](cache[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

So I have these two lines before

```
cacheManager.registerCallback("SOMEOBJECT", loadSomeOBJECT);
cacheManager.setData('SOMEOBJECT', api._function);
```

and I am getting this error:

```
ERROR
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'then'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic]
#0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:42)
#1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#2      CacheManager.setData.<anonymous closure> (chrome-extension://ekfcndmmkincdeoolhcebmhcgmkmadip/helpers.dart:27:31)
#3      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1149)
#4      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:551)
#5      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:637)
#6      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:424)
#7      _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:479)
#8      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#9      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50)
#10     _ScheduleImmediateHelper._handleMutation (dart:html:49254)
#11     MutationObserver._create.<anonymous closure> (dart:html:27525)​
```

this refer to the line which setData and callback from cache object. then the cache object will call the api.function to get the data from server, and then the raw data is served, it goes to process method in SOMEOBJECT class and return the MAP of JSON representation. Once the data back to cache manager to call the `then` on the `future object` it fails. with the error on the question. Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a brief look and saw

```
Future _function(){
 var future = _getWithID('path');
  return future.then((data) {
```

is missing a return. There might be other issues though.

Comment: It was a silly mistake, thanks for point it out. sometimes you get blind on simple things.

Comment: That's a common error with async code. Are you aeare of `async` and `await`. Makes async code much easier to work with.